# How to download an user selected file to the Angular "assets" folder

Tags: client-side, angular6

This is what I would like to do:

1. The user selectes a file by his browser
2. When the user clicks a button, the selected file is saved to Angular "assets" folder

**Please note** that I use client-side Angular 6, not server-side one.

To do the second step, I'm pretty sure I could do an AJAX request to my web hosting to save the file using PHP, but I'm interested to know if there is a easier way to do that using directly Angular, considering that Angular files are placed server-side.

Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some kind of server-side techniques. PHP/Nodejs/... 
You do not need classic AJAX. Actually, Angular is based on AJAX concept. So use Angular's HttpClientModule to make GET/POST/PUT requests.
More details and an example on https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: So do you advice to do a POST request to store the file? This solution requires PHP. Is there no other way to avoid using PHP?

Comment: There is no other way. You can't avoid server-side part.